# google site map not working since pretty codeigniter urls

Tags: codeigniter, seo, google-search-console

Okay, what is happening!? I switched to pretty urls using code igniter; `http://robertwaynehq.com/what-we-do` rather than the same with `.php`

I then updated the site map file and it doesn't seem to like that the pages have no extension. Further the google webmaster site is giving a redirect error. Yet the pages work. Help?

**Edit:** I do have the redirects in the old files.

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://mydomain.com/what-we-do" ); 
?>
```

The real issue is that I have updated the sitemap.xml and google webmaster tools doesn't seem to like or recognize the files.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset>        
    <url>
      <loc>http://mydomain.com/</loc>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://mydomain.com/index.php</loc>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://mydomain.com/what-we-do</loc>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <!-- and so on for each page... -->
    </urlset>
```

Answer (score 0):

set 301 redirect in the old php files, redirecting to the url of the page

[Google Webmaster Tools help on 301 Redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633)

[301 Redirect in PHP](http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=301+redirect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=m0L&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=301+redirect+php&pbx=1&oq=301+redirect+php&aq=f&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2367l4608l0l4835l10l5l3l1l1l0l200l695l2.2.1l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=51476381e1d069ce&biw=1680&bih=927)